# How can I find the start of a range in an automated way?

Tags: clustering, binning, range

I am looking at real estate sales data for different regions. I bin the data by sold price range in 1000 increments (see below). I am looking to find the start of the price range or cluster in which most lots sold. In the first image I would say the sales start at 9-10K and in the second image they start at 16-17K. There are some sold below those prices but I would consider them outliers.

I am trying to figure out an automated way of finding the start of the price range where most lots sell. I want to be able to iterate this for a large number of regions. Do you have any suggestions for methods which would accomplish this? Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your criterion "the start of the price range where most lots sell" is somewhat vague.

- In the first region, you pick \$9-10 thousand rather than
  \$10-11 thousand (presumably because 9-10 is already on the up-slope
  toward the "lower" modal interval (with the "upper" modal interval at 19-20.
- In the second region, I suppose you choose the modal interval 16-17 itself because there were no sales in 15-16.

Both choices seem a bit arbitrary, (a) because the rule seems slightly different in each case and (b) because you would have gotten different answers if you had chosen different histogram
bins (say 7.5-8.5, ..., 21.5-22.5).

Moreover, you mention that you'd regard the lowest prices in both regions might be considered "outliers," but this criterion for
outliers does not match any of the usual ones--certainly not the boxplot criterion for outliers.  And you say nothing about be
bimodal pattern of prices in both region, nor whether all of your
regions tend to have multiple modes.

I'm wondering if it might serve your purposes better to find a value halfway between the 1st and 4th percentiles, and use that as the
dollar amount above which meaningful sales begin. I don't have actual
values for either region, so let's consider what happens in the three
fictitious regions simulated below?

I don't understand your objectives clearly enough to recommend
using lower percentiles to get your "low" value, but looking at
these fictitious datasets may help you decide what you want to use. [None of the 'related' links in the margin of this page is a duplicate of your question, but you might get additional ideas by browsing them.]

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = c(rnorm(40, 12, 3), rnorm(60, 16, 4))
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.298  11.499  14.844  14.983  17.721  27.550 
cutp = seq(0,30,1)
hist(x1, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 low = round(mean(quantile(x1, c(.01,.04))))
 abline(v = low, col="orange", lw=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

With slightly different binning:

```
cutp = seq(.5,30,1)
hist(x1, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = low, col="orange", lw=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

```
set.seed(511)
x2 = c(rnorm(20, 13, 3), rnorm(30, 16, 4))
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  6.551  11.664  14.320  14.219  16.265  25.885 
cutp = seq(0,30,1)
hist(x2, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 low = round(mean(quantile(x2, c(.01,.04))))
 abline(v = low, col="orange", lw=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Strictly speaking, my general rule gives $8$ above, but I might move it to $9$ because of the gap.

```
set.seed(1234)
x3 = rnorm(70, 14, 4)
summary(x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.617  10.048  11.975  12.899  15.287  24.196 
cutp = seq(0,30,1)
hist(x3, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 low = round(mean(quantile(x3, c(.01,.04))))
 abline(v = low, col="orange", lw=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Strictly speaking, my rule gives $6,$ but I might move it
to $5$ pr $7,$ depending on my interpretation of counts in $(4,8).$

Also, here are boxplots of each of the three fictitious datasets
used above--in case you want to use some value along the lower "whisker"
of a boxplot as you "low" value.

```
 boxplot(x1,x2,x3, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]